# How to remove duplicate entries in an ArrayList

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList<Integer>` that is full of years that it pulls from my database i want to know how it is possible to loop through them so i can remove duplicates.
Thanks in Advance,
Dean

Comment: I'd rather let the DB do the filtering work using SQL so that it returns exactly the results you want. It'll do the task undoubtely more efficient than Java can ever do.

Comment: By the way: [java+remove+duplicates+from+list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+remove+duplicates+from+list) :)

Comment: In addition, it requires less data to be sent from the database to the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Set` instead of a `List` if duplicates shouldn't exist.

You can either use a `Set` where you're currently using your `List`, or you can use the `Set` to remove duplicate elements.

```
Set<Integer> years = new HashSet<Integer>(myOldArrayList);
```

Or you could transform from one collection to another.  I'm not sure what performance implications there are:

```
ArrayList<Integer> years = // populate from database
years = new ArrayList<Integer>(new HashSet<Integer>(years));
```

Answer (score 3):

If the order doesn't matter, just make a `Set` out of them, and then back to list again if needed:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(yourList);
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(set);
```

Comment: And if the order matters, use `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: If order doesn't matter, he should probably be using a Set in the first place and not worry about duplicates in the first place.

Comment: @BalusC: Good idea, I didn't think about that one.

Answer (score 2):

Off the cuff, will a `new ArrayList<Integer>(new HashSet<Integer>(your_list))` work? Oh, don't forget sorting.